# how to center image in react-multi-carousel?

Tags: reactjs, react-multi-carousel, pure-react-carousel

I'm new to react, trying to build brand carousel using react-multi-carousel.
The images are displayed properly but I want to center the image. Tried to write css it did not apply on the carousel. How this can be achieved, Or do I have to use any other carousel?
`

```
<Grid item xs={12}>
 <Carousel
   responsive={responsive}
   infinite={true}
   arrows={true}>
       <Image src={abt.logo_carousel.url}responsive/>
       <Image src={abt.logo_carousel1.url}responsive/>
       <Image src={abt.logo_carousel2.url}responsive/>
       <Image src={abt.logo_carousel3.url}responsive/>
 </Carousel>
</Grid>`
```

Comment: you can include your code for better understanding

Comment: @AnonymousCoder I have added the code

Comment: what do you need to be centered image or complete carousel ??

Comment: the logos inside the div of carousel. in above case the image inside

Comment: your images are already centered inside the carousel container

Comment: so do you need your carousel to be centered in the body ??

Comment: no the images are not centered

Answer (score 1):

write style inside your tag itself.like this

`<img src="..." style={{width:300,marginLeft:"auto",marginRight:"auto"}}   />`

Comment: Style works but to display the item in center it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little bit late but hope this could help someone (it worked for me):

```
<img src={source} style={{marginLeft: "auto", marginRight: "auto", display: "flex", justifyContent: "center"}}/>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).